# Book recommendation: Olympiad Polynomial & Functional Equation.

Tags: polynomials, functional-equations, book-recommendation

I've just entered Highschool in Vietnam, i really want to participate in Math Olympiad (National Olympiad, TST and maybe IMO even though I know it's hard). Functional equation and Polynomial are the topics that I have least knowledge so I want to find some good books for them.

I found "Awesome Polynomials for Mathematics Competitions" and "Topics in Functional Equations – 3rd Edition" by Titu Andresscu, but i don't know if they are worth reading. Do these books provide all the theories, techniques, skills for Olympiad? I want some reviews about them.

Also, what are some good books for these Topics, if the above two books are not good?

Comment: You aim high. It’s good.
However, to be able to represent the country for the IMO, you need to win in the second contest round, and the condition for participate the second round is that you need among 40-50 students in the national olympiad (first round). Each round seems to have different kinds of problem that you should know and train before. If your high school uses to have students who achieve national (or international) prizes, you should ask your math teachers. They have secret training documents.

Comment: Many online resources like https://web.evanchen.cc/problems.html, https://yufeizhao.com/olympiad/geolemmas.pdf, https://usamo.wordpress.com/tag/olympiad/. Also this book The Mathematical Olympiad Handbook: An Introduction to Problem Solving Based
by Anthony Gardiner (Oxford University Press), etc.

Comment: @NN2 thanks for your suggestion. Yes, I can tell that my school has the best performance in Math Olympiad and used to have gold IMO (I don't mean to brag). I've ask my teachers about the Resources/Books, but they have their own materials and rarely share them (Because of copyright issue). I don't think doing their homework is enough and I want some books/resources for self learning.

Comment: @JeanMarie those resources are amazing, but I want some that provide theories, techniques though. Also that book by Anthony Gardiner seem a litte too old and too general?